# How can I secure Orbeon Form Runner with an IP filter?

Tags: java, orbeon

The [documentation here](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/link-embed/liferay-proxy-portlet.html#securing-form-runner-with-an-ip-filter) describes how to secure Form Runner with an IP Filter. I followed those instructions as follows:

1. Put urlrewrite-3.2.0.jar in the Orbeon Forms WEB-INF/lib folder
2. Configure the filter in Orbeon Forms WEB-INF/web.xml

```xml
    <filter>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

3. Put the `urlrewrite.xml` configuration in the Orbeon WEB-INF folder

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <urlrewrite>
        <rule>
            <condition type="remote-addr" operator="notequal">0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0</condition>
            <condition type="remote-addr" operator="notequal">127.0.0.1</condition>
            <set type="status">403</set>
            <to type="temporary-redirect" last="true">/unauthorized</to>
        </rule>
    </urlrewrite>
```

If I access this URL from localhost it works fine as expected:

`http://myserver.mydomain.com/orbeon/fr/`

If I access it from anywhere else I am not able to access Form Runner, which is good, but the redirect does not work correctly. I end up getting redirected to the following URL which does not include the application context, so I get a 404.

`http://myserver.mydomain.com/unauthorized`

I tried changing the value for `temporary-redirect` to `/%{context-path}/unauthorized` but then I get redirected to `http://orbeon/unauthorized`. I also tried `%{context-path}/unauthorized` but then I get a "too many redirects" error.

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: And I imagine that putting the actual context there isn't an option for you? E.g. if you have the web app deployed on `/forms`, have `/forms/unauthorized`?

Comment: Also, `%{context-path}/unauthorized` looks like the correct way to do it, but the rule will catch this again, hence the "too many redirects" error. Actually, it seems to be that you shouldn't do a redirect in this case, just return a 403. Would that work for you?

Comment: @avernet Putting the actual context there wasn't ideal since it is not the same in all environments. It would have been workable. It didn't really help though. As you said, the rule catches this again. I tried including another condition `<condition type="path-info" operator="notequal">/unauthorized</condition>` (and variations: `unauthorized`, `forms/unauthorized`, `/forms/unauthorized`) so the rule wouldn't catch it again but it didn't have any effect. I was able to get it to just return a 403 but needed to add `<to>null</to>`. I recommend updating the documentation. See answer below.

Comment: Perfect! I've replaced the `<to type="temporary-redirect" last="true">/unauthorized</to>` by `<to>null</to>` in the documentation as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the IP Filter to simply return a 403 without redirecting the URL. In my case, this is more desirable.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
        <condition type="remote-addr" operator="notequal">0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0</condition>
        <condition type="remote-addr" operator="notequal">127.0.0.1</condition>
        <set type="status" last="true">403</set>
        <to>null</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

I found `to>null</to>` on a list of examples here: http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/4.0/guide.html